# render_site() function destroys hypertext links

Tags: html, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I created an html document with the help of Quarto, a R package.
This document is a dictionary of datatables and their respective content.

At the beginning of the html, I have a *toc* (list of all tables' name) and you can click on each name to go down to this table (instead of scrolling down or CTRL F).

This html document, along with others, is then embedded into a website with the help of render_site() function from Rmarkdown package.

But in the resulting website, the links don't work anymore. The toc content is still highlighted (in green, not in blue anymore) and underlined, but clicking on it doesn't do anything but modifying the link in the searchbar: instead of `...data-quality/dico.html`, now i got `...data-quality/dico.html#crm_contact` but it does not go down to the table crm_contact.